# Bootstrap Modal onmouseover

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

So I am working on my personal webpage, and this is my first development with Bootstrap. I am using php, html, css, and JS as my dev stack. The error I am having is trying to create an element that:
1. If a php test passes, create a div, and in the JS, attach an onemouseover event (I know how to do this piece)
2. I want a bootstrap modal to open and transition onmouseoever, and close, onmouseleave. 
This is the code so far, the createModal function is empty, as using this.innerHTML = blahblahblah didn't work.

```
        <?php 
        if(!isset($_GET["nfc"])){
            $nfc = false;
        } else {
            $nfc = filter_var($_GET["nfc"], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        }
    ?>

<?php 
        if ($nfc == true) { ?>
            <a href="#"
            id="nfc"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#basicModal"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-5x"></i></a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-5x"></i>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

JS:
    var element = document.getElementById("nfc");
        if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
            element.onmouseover = createModal;
        }

Comment: You can not close modal on a.onmouseleave. Modal window cover your link when showing. Try to use [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) and code js like this: `$("#basicModal").popover({trigger: 'hover'});`

Comment: I now realize WHY you can't make a modal disappear onmouseleave, as the focus of the page when a modal appears shifts entirely to the modal itself. I don't want t use popover's, as this modal only appears in very specific scenarios, I want the alert to be very obvious. Since the Modal contains both an exit button, usually a close button, and also disappears when you click outside it's boundaries, the question now becomes, how do I ACTIVATE a modal only onmouseover?

Comment: `$('#nfc').hover(function () { $("#basicModal").modal('show'); });` . And remove `data-toggle` attributes (to disable the show modal click actions). Read ["Usage"](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show hide your modal by using the following jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("body").find("#nfc").hover(function() {
      $("#basicModal").modal('show');
  }, function(){
      $("#basicModal").modal('hide');                            
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, quick question! The modal is currently working when I wrap it in my window.onload function. Within that function is this code                                                                                                       var element = document.getElementById("nfc");
  if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
   $(element).modal('show');
  }                                    Is this redundant?

Comment: you have written you code in plain javascript, and the code which i have written is in JQuery which is a plugin built in javascript, today every one using jquery and doing the work which can also be done in javascript but the jquery makes our work more easier than javascript.